# Как добавлять элементы в массив по нажатию через OnClickListener или OnTouchListener?

Tags: android

Пожалуйста помогите заранее благодарю за ответ

Comment: Приведите код, что вы попробовали и что вызвало затруднение?

Answer (score 3):

К примеру, у Вас следующий код в MainActivity:

```
int arr [100] = new int [];
int i = 0;
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        arr [i] = i;
    }
});
```

Все просто, не правда ли?